# How to find the number of nodes returned in an API response using postman?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, postman, functional-testing

Suppose the following is the API response:

```
{
    "content": 
    [
        {
            "id": 90008,
            "capacity": 2,
            "manufacturer": "NISSAN",
            "model": "Sunny",
            "comment": "Nice Compact car.",
            "features": {
                "high_grade": false,
                "normal_grade": true
            },
            "images": [
                {
                    "type": "OUTSIDE",
                    "url": "http://some-image-1.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "type": "INSIDE",
                    "url": "http://some-image-2.jpg"
                }
            ],
            "links": []
        },
        {
            "id": 90009,
            "capacity": 7,
            "manufacturer": "Audi",
            "model": "Q7",
            "comment": "Very good leg space!",
            "features": {
                "high_grade": true,
                "normal_grade": false
            },
            "images": [
                {
                    "type": "OUTSIDE",
                    "url": "http://some-image-1.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "type": "INSIDE",
                    "url": "http://some-image-2.jpg"
                }
            ],
            "links": []
        }
    ],
    "page": {
        "size": 20,
        "total_elements": 2,
        "total_pages": 1,
        "number": 0
    }
}
```

Now in postman, how will I find out that the total number of parent/main nodes returned in content is 8 which is as follows:

1. id
2. capacity
3. manufacturer
4. model
5. comment
6. features
7. images
8. links

I tried with the following but it failed:

```
pm.test("Check total no. of nodes in all content is 8", () => {
    for (i = 0; i < jsonData.content.length; i++) { 
        pm.expect(Object.keys(jsonData.content[i]).length).to.equal(8);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is the length of the object important? If the value of the property changes it would change the profile of the data so you could have 8 different things returned and the test would still pass. Are you also sure it’s not 0 indexed - If so it would be 7 and not 8.

Comment: Yes - for now, to me, the length of the object is important.
I am also checking each returned node names and their values as well.
Yes - the 0 indexed nodes, such as links, can be ignored.

Comment: Added an answer - Does this work for you?

Comment: this might be off topic. but how did you get this response? I tried /entity/node?format_json but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is just missing:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json()
```

Which the test would have told you when it was ran and gave you the `Check total no. of nodes in all content is 8 | ReferenceError: jsonData is not defined` message.

So it should look something like this:

```
pm.test("Check total no. of nodes in all content is 8", () => {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json()
    for (i = 0; i < jsonData.content.length; i++) { 
        console.log(Object.keys(jsonData.content[i]))
        pm.expect(Object.keys(jsonData.content[i]).length).to.equal(8);
    }
});
```

You mentioned that `The 0 indexed nodes, such as links, can be ignored` but the way that you have your test and what you're checking for would include them anyway. They are also part of the list that you attached to the question.

I added the line `console.log(Object.keys(jsonData.content[i]))` to show you that in the Postman Console.

[image: Console Output]

Comment: Thanks a bunch once again Danny! It finally worked perfectly. I apologise for the delayed response though.

Comment: You’re welcome. If you’re happy, please accept the answer and close out the question.